# Where is Valyria located in the world of Planetos?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I was recently having a discussion with another user about whether or not the Doom of Valyria could have had a hand in the odd season lengths that occur in Westeros. Their point was that following large scale volcanic activity a long winter could occur due to all the extra debris in the sky. For more information see [Nuclear Winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter). I told the user it appears there isn't much evidence as too what happened to Valyria and the surrounding lands following the Doom. However, I'm not sure where Valyria is on Planetos and if it the effects of the Doom could even impact Westeros.

So that leads to the question where is Valyria?

Comment: I think the big problem with the theory is the timeline. The Doom happened 400-500 years ago in Westeros history (and is reasonably well documented, even if we don't know the cause, we know when it happened), whereas tales of the Long Night date back 5-8000 years suggesting the seasons have been odd for at least an order of magnitude longer than the time since the Doom.

Comment: @delinear I know, the question isn't about their theory (something which I didn't accept and used points similar to yours in response) but simply where Valyria is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exists beyond Westeros, North of the Wall and the Free Cities?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114440/what-exists-beyond-westeros-north-of-the-wall-and-the-free-cities)

Comment: @skooba Weird, I answered that supposed duplicate, and I didn't even *mention* Valyria (let alone pinpoint where it was), because it wasn't relevant to a question that's mostly about what's north of the wall (I added a few notes about Ulthos etc only as a bonus "since you're interested in locations not central to the plot"). In fact "Valyria" doesn't even *appear* on that page. We shouldn't retrofit an old, answered, already very broad question into a way-too-broad "brain-dump everything about every location in ASOIAF" wiki page. Related: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11475/

Comment: @user568458 My thoughts exactly, I think the reason for the dupe vote is because it includes the world map though I did have a quick search for Valyria on the page and didn't find it mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valyria is on the south coast of Essos, it is situated on an island east of Volantis and west of Slaver Bay and the Slaver Cities of Meereeen, Yunkai and Astapor. It is bounded by The Gulf of Grief to the east and the Summer Sea. It is now seperated from mainland Essos by The Smoking Sea to the north which connects Valyria with the Lands of the Long Summer.

The following images are taken from [this website](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/2013/03/official-world-map-of-a-song-of-ice-and-fire/) which I believe takes them from The Lands of Ice and Fire, [the canon maps](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175058/58193).

In the map of The Known World you can see Valyria is slightly south of the centre image as the darker landmass south of Essos.

[image: The Known World map]

The following map is of Central Essos where you can see the area around Valyria clearer and how it is now seperated from the mainland.

[image: Central Essos map]

To see a higher resolotion of The Known World map see [this picture](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2855/33912305140_f09f5c7a78_o.jpg).

Answer (score 5):

[image: Map of Platentos] Valyria is circled in the above image. When Tyrion is heading toward Slaver Bay in the books it mentions his ship navigating around Valyria.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, is this a canon image?

Comment: Side note the circle encompasses Valyria, The Smoking Sea and The Lands of the Long Summer.